# Open containing folder of recent document

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016

Is there any way to open the folder of a recent document in win10, by e.g. rightclicking on the shortcut to the document? Trying to do this from the menu recent documents opened in an office program doesn't seem to indicate this is possible, but I am sure I could do this in earlier versions of Windows. Have I forgotten something obvious, or is this functionality which has been removed from the OS?

[image]

Comment: 'Open File Location' is a right-click option for Recent Files under Quick Access in File Explorer. But I've never seen it in a Jump LIst.

Comment: You knew it, Keith! Two methods: [Open File location option removed in win 10 (Q to Ramesh - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/open-file-location-option-removed-in-win-10-q-to/0ee3d99c-6c30-47e0-94e2-cee1908e9399?auth=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the lines below to Notepad and save it with `.reg` extension.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\opencontainingfoldermenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"
```

Double-click the file to apply the settings to the registry.

Right-clicking an item in the Excel Jumplists should now show the `Open File Location` option.

***Note:*** I don't have Office 2016 installed so could not test the registry edit for `.xlsx` file type. But, it works fine when I applied it for `txtfile`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should work, though I am a bit curious what the hex-code after the @ is? Anyway, I ended up using the powershell script provided by Keith A. Miller in the link you provided in an earlier comment, if you want to include that in your answer as well.

Comment: Hmm. And after having tried it out, it appears that I do get the "Open File Location" option now for files which are stored locally now, but not for files stored on the network, like on OneDrive or SharePoint. I guess you don't know if it's a different handler I'll have to include the reg-edit in for it to show up for those as well?

Comment: `{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}` GUID adds the "Open Containing Folder Menu". The extension is powered by the file`C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll`

Keith's PS script adds the same GUID as the .reg file.

The shell extension works only for local files.

Comment: Well, obviously it only works for local files, or I wouldn't have asked if you knew how to extend the solution to include network files. As for the script it is quite a bit faster and more readable than creating a reg file, especially when dealing with several extensions (ppt, pptx, pptm, etc), which is why I recommeded you added it to your answer.